# Relationship between radon-nikodym derivatives and total variation distance

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, radon-nikodym, total-variation

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})$ be a measure space on which we have defined two probability measures $P$ and $Q$. Let $f$ and $g$ denote Radon-Nikodym derivatives of $P$ and $Q$ with respect to a $\sigma$-finite dominating measure $\mu$. Define the total variation distance between $P$ and $Q$ as $$\text{TV}(P,Q)=\sup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}|P(A)-Q(A)|.$$I asked another question on the relationship between these derivatives $f$ and $g$ and the distance $\text{TV}(P,Q)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447491/question-on-relation-between-radon-nikodym-derivatives-and-the-total-variation-d). I am reading some notes which claim that$$\text{TV}^2(P,Q)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\mathcal{X}|f(x)-g(x)|d\mu(x)$$ seemingly without any further justification. I would greatly appreciate someone telling me why this is the case, as even having asked the seperate question above, I can't see this as a consequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure there should be a square on the $\text{TV}(P,Q)$ term? Or maybe $\text{TV}^2(P,Q)$ means something else?

From your previous question you already have that
$$
\text{TV}(P,Q)= P(A)-Q(A)= \int_A |f(x)-g(x)|\, d\mu(x),
$$
where $A= \{ x: f(x)-g(x)>0\}$.

By the same arguments you can get
$$
\text{TV}(P,Q)= Q(A^c)-P(A^c)= \int_{A^c} |g(x)-f(x)|\, d\mu(x).
$$
Summing these up we get
$$
2\text{TV}(P,Q) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} |f(x)-g(x)|\, d\mu(x).
$$

Comment: The solution I am looking at certainly does include a square, although there could be a mistake in the typing, and given I can't find a problem with your answer I think that this must be the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use $|f-g| = (f-g)^+ + (f-g)^-$, where $h^+ = \max(h,0)$, $h^- = -\min(h,0)$, and the answer you received to your other question, it seems like the desired formula should fall out.